# Splitting a Scrapy element among multiple CSV rows

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I've been working on something that I think should be relatively easy but I keep hitting my head against a wall.  I've tried multiple similar solutions from stackoverflow and I've improved my code but still stuck on the basic functionality.

I am scraping a web page that returns an element (genre) that is essential a list of genres:

```
Mystery, Comedy, Horror, Drama
```

The xpath returns perfectly.  I'm using a Scrapy pipeline to output to a CSV file.  What I'd like to do is create a separate row for each item in the above list along with the page url:

```
"Mystery", "http:domain.com/page1.html"
"Comedy", "http:domain.com/page1.html"
```

No matter what I try I can only output:

```
"Mystery, Comedy, Horror, Drama", ""http:domain.com/page1.html"
```

Here's my code:

```
def parse_genre (self, response):
    for item in [i.split (',') for i in response.xpath ('//span [contains (@class, "genre")]/text()').extract()]:
        sg = ItemLoader (item=ItemGenre (), response=response)
        sg.add_value ('url', response.url)
        sg.add_value ('genre', item, MapCompose(str.strip))
        yield sg.load_item ()
```

This is called from the main parse routine for the spider.  That all functions correctly.  (I have two items on each web page.  The main spider gathers the "parent" information and this function is attempting to gather "child" information.  Technically not a child record, but definitely a 1 to many relationship.)

I've tried a number of possible solutions.  This is the only version that makes sense to me and seems like it should work.  I'm sure I'm just not splitting the genre string correctly.

Comment: This is a perfect problem for debugger. Just insert `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` above `sg = ` line and run the crawler. Debugger will prompt you into shell and there you can see what's going on, i.e. type `item` to see what's the value of this variable. :)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm still pretty new with Python and not sure I'm getting all the tricks yet.  I'll run through the debugger to see how I can take a closer look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. 
Your culprit seems to be the way you are getting your items:

```
[i.split(',') for i in response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "genre")]/text()').extract()]
```

Without having the source I can't correct you fully but it is obvious here your code is returning a list of lists.

You should either flatten this list of lists into list of strings or iterate through it appropriately:

```
items = response.xpath('//span[contains (@class, "genre")]/text()').extract()]
for item in items:
    for category in item.split(','):
        sg = ItemLoader(item=ItemGenre(), response=response)
        sg.add_value('url', response.url)
        sg.add_value('genre', category, MapCompose(str.strip))
        yield sg.load_item ()
```

Alternative more advance technique would be to use list nested comprehension:

```
items = response.xpath('//span[contains (@class, "genre")]/text()').extract()]
# good cheatsheet to remember this [leaf for tree in forest for leaf in tree]
categories = [cat for item in items for cat in items]
for category in categories:
    sg = ItemLoader(item=ItemGenre(), response=response)
    sg.add_value('url', response.url)
    sg.add_value('genre', category, MapCompose(str.strip))
    yield sg.load_item ()
```

Comment: Brilliant!  The first response did the trick.  I am going to work through the second one as well.  I love tight code that reads well.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Cheers! If you could click "accept answer" checkmark to the left of the post I'd be great :)